# Windows Backup is stuck after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-7-backup

After upgrading to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8, the (Windows 7 backup) which was a part of Windows 8 is no longer available in 8.1, but for some reason (I guess because the back progress was running while upgrading to Windows 8.1) the process is still running for a month now after the upgrade:

[image]

When I try to click on it to view it, I get the following error 'Access is denied. (0x80070005)':

[image]

I could not find any solution for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the Windows Backup activity and stop/disable/remove it in the Windows Task Scheduler. The scheduled task has probably survived from before upgrading to 8.1.